# Android App Bundle, Disable Language and Density Split on Base Module or All module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, gradle-plugin, app-bundle

I have created android app bundle and I want to disable the split apk by language and density, since ours is a huge project, and we have shared resources.

Question is, when I read both developer site and medium blog from android, they ask to add

```
android {
   bundle {
     density { 
       enableSplit = false
     }
     language { 
      enableSplit = false
     }
   }
}
```

**Should we add this only in baseModule(application) build.gralde or each modules build.gradle** if I have multiple feature modules.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to put it in all your gradle files. You can put it only in your `app.gradle` file as follow:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion project.sdk

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```